# Sequelize update a record and it's associations

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a model City which hasMany CitiesDescriptions.
I would like to update City, but whenever the data contains CitiesDescriptions I would like them to be updated as well. 
This is what my data looks like:

```
{
  "id": 4263,
  "name": "Accra",
  "country_id": 9,
  "slug": "accra-5",
  "code": "ACD",
  "hdo_code": "",
  "tourico_code": null,
  "active": true,
  "CitiesDescriptions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "lang": "es",
      "description": "text text"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, in this case I want the data within CitiesDescriptions to be updated.
In the case that one of the objects inside CitiesDescriptions is a new record (doesn't have ID) I want it to be created.

Anyway, I haven't found a way to do this, whatever I found fails in some way. The closest I found that almost works is this:

```
var city = models.City.build(params, {
    isNewRecord : false,
    include : [models.CitiesDescription]
  });

  Promise.all([
    city.save(),
    city.CitiesDescriptions.map(function (description) {
      if (description.getDataValue('id')) {
        return description.save();
      } else {
        description.city_id = city.id;
        return models.CitiesDescription.create(description.dataValues);
      }
    })
  ]).then(function(results) {
    res.send(results);
  });
```

This works except with the data doesn't have a CitiesDescriptions key.
Still, looks way to complicated to do, specially if tomorrow I have more associated models.

Isn't there any way to do this without so much hassle?

EDIT:

Couldnt find a solution, I made this and it works as intended.

```
var params = req.body;
  var promises = [];
  promises.push(models.City.update(params, {
    where: {
      id: parseInt(req.params.id)
    }
  }));

  if(params.CitiesDescriptions) {
    promises.push(
      params.CitiesDescriptions.map(function (description) {
        return models.CitiesDescription.upsert(description, {individualHooks: true});
      })
    );
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    res.send(results);
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `upsert`? I think this should achieve what you want

Comment: So, it works now? Glad I could help